# C++ modulus by 2 performance

Tags: c++, performance, modulus

I was wondering what the typical compiler's assembly reduction would be when performing an integer modulus by 2 operation such as this:

```
const char* integer_string = "300"; // avoid compiler optimization
int i = atoi(integer_string);
int b = i % 2; // the line in question
```

I'd imagine the compiler could turn it into a bit-wise operation to just check that last bit (1s place), but does it do this?

Comment: Which compiler ? What platform ?

Comment: At least with most reasonably recent compilers I've seen, yes, it'll do this.

Comment: Since this is such a basic optimization, you can count on nearly all compilers to do it. The only sure way, of course, is to check your with your specific compiler...

Answer (score 8):

The question only makes sense in the context of a particular compiler, platform, optimization options etc.

My compiler (`gcc 4.7.2` on `x86_64`) does do this when `-O3` optimizations are turned on:

```
    andl    $1, %esi
```

Comment: @Matt: (1) Compile to assembly (`-S` if using `gcc`). (2) Examine the assembly.

Comment: generate assembly, examine assembly, find which line in the assembly you really care about :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Good point. Step 3 is generally the trickiest.